# Place Image from UIWebView into UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have a UIWebView hidden in the background of my app that loads a site, and I want to place one of the images loaded from it into a visible UIImageView. Because the image I'm loading is a PHP session-based captcha, I can't just load the image directly from it's URL into the UIImageView, I have to get the particular instance that is loaded into the UIWebView. Can anyone give me a couple of pointers on how I would go about approaching this? I can't seem to know where to start...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This snippet grabs a 50x50 pixel square with an origin of (50,50) on the webview. Adjust the positions to the position of the captcha (if you know it is always in the same place).

```
UIImage* theImage;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(50,50));
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -50, -50 );
[[[self webView] layer] renderInContext:context];
theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
// now do stuff with theImage
```

You may find you need to put this code (or your version of it) in a webViewDidFinishLoad: method in the webView delegate. Webviews, even basic ones, often take ages to render. If you grab the image too soon, you won't get what you want.

Comment: This is on the right track of what I want... but I think you misunderstood, I need to access a particular image within the UIWebView (loaded in an <img> tag), not the entire UIWebView.

Comment: I've amended the code above. You can set the size of the image you want to grab in the CGContextRef function and then the position using CGContextTranslate. (Watch out for different co-ordinate systems.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm putting that in my code now, I'll see if it works.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's working, because when I compile it, it returns 
"No '-renderInContext:' method found"...

Comment: You need to add the CoreGraphics framework to your project and add an import in the appropriate header file: #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>. If you do that, it should compile OK.

Answer (score 1):

Hi
If you can modify your PHP page, create a Javascript which give you the url of the captcha image.
after use the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString on your UIWebView

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the question... I have the URL of the image, but the actual image itself changes... which is why I have to get that particular instance of the image that is in the UIWebView.

Comment: each time you call the url of your image, the image change? that's it?

Comment: Yes, that's it. So that's why I can't just pull the image directly from it's URL, I need the exact instance of the image being displayed in the UIWebView so I can submit the user's form for them.

Comment: The only way i see is to render your webview in a CGBitmapContext. In order to use it after to create an UIImage.

Answer (score 1):

What you can try :

1. Make a javascript which get the image data as string (try canvas.getImageData, not sure it's implemented in Safari)
2. Get this string with stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString
3. Convert the NSString to NSData
4. And after init an image with NSData...